# It is possible to parallelize an ActiveRecord callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, activerecord, parallel-processing, callback

I created a method called `create_layer_roles` that need to be executed everytime a resource Map is created but I don't want to wait until this method ends.

**map.rb**

```
class Map < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_and_belongs_to_many :layers,
    after_add: :create_layers_roles,

  def create_layers_roles
    Thread.new do
      # A lot of inserts in DB
      ...

      # Close DB connection
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close
    end
  end
end
```

I tried to parallelize it but I did not succeed because the creation flow waits for the callback to finish its execution to continue.

It's possible to continue the flow without waiting callback execution?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you´re beyond the scope of where a model callback is the right tool. I would look into using a service object in conjunction with an ActiveJob.

Comment: totally agree, background job is more appropriate here.